# How do I use specific service in e2e jest test NestJS

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing

​

I am trying to test my login scenario with jest e2e in NestJS.

When i login or register it will send verification code with sms to me and if I hardcode sms code or change my logic to bypass it, the whole testing case falls apart.

Is there anyway to inject my other services into my app.e2e-spec.ts and use it in my test case to query the verification code?

I tried using direct mongoose connection to get the verification code but it seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Nest provides the [`.overrideProvider`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing) API for this reason while you are compiling your test application. You should be able to do something like

```js
describe('E2E suite', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let url: string;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    })
    .overrideProvider(ProviderToOverride)
    .useValue(mockOfTheProvider)
    .compile();
    app = modRef.createNestApplication();
    await app.listen(0); // listen on random port
    url = await app.getUrl();
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
  ...tests
});
```